# How to replace multiple words in a line with another words

Tags: replace, discord, discord.py, keyword

i have recently started building a bot in discord.py and got stuck in this situation here

```
@client.command()
async def replace(ctx, *, arg):
     msg = f"{arg}" .format(ctx.message).replace('happe', '<:happe:869470107066302484>')
     await ctx.send(msg)
```

this is a command which replaces the word "happe" with the emoji so this looks like :

**Command : {prefix}replace i am very happe**

Result : i am very "emoji for happe"

but i want to make it so we can replace multiple words with different emoji and not just a single one like

**Command : {prefix}replace i am not happe, i am sad**

Result : i am not "emoji for happe", i am "emoji for sad"

is there a way to edit multiple words in just one sentence like using a json file of making a list of emojis and its id?
also this command doesnt seems to work in cogs and says command is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to edit multiple words in just one sentence like using a json file ot making a list of emojis and its id?

Yes, you can do just that. Make a list of word-emoji pairs and iterate over all of them to replace every word.

```py
async def replace(ctx, *, arg):
    l = [("happe", "<:happe:869470107066302484>"), ("sad", "..."), ...]
    msg = arg  # Making a copy here to avoid editing the original arg in case you want to use it at some point
    for word, emoji in l:
        msg = msg.replace(word, emoji)
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

> also this command doesnt seems to work in cogs and says command is invalid

In **cogs** the decorator is `@commands.command()`, **not** `@client.command()`. Don't forget the `from discord.ext import commands` import to get access to it.

Lastly, I'm a bit confused what `f"{arg}" .format(ctx.message)` is supposed to be doing? You can remove the `.format` and the `f-string` entirely. `args` is already a `string` so putting it in an `f-string` with nothing else has no effect, and `.format(ctx.message)` doesn't do anything either. The result of that entire thing is the same as just `arg`.

```py
>>> arg = "this is the arg"
>>> f"{arg}".format("this has no effect")
'this is the arg'
```

Comment: honestly i am a bit confused with python cause im very new to it rn and was thinking using args and stuff would be a good idea. For the cogs, yes i did replaced client to commands but it isnt helping anyways its optional. Thank you very much for the explanation though, a really big help and works perfectly :D